# Spark installation on Hadoop Yarn

Tags: bash, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

please someone help me, i am trying to install spark on Haoop Yarn, i am getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:379)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
```

and hadoop daemons are :

```
4064 SecondaryNameNode
3478 NameNode
4224 ResourceManager
4480 NodeManager
3727 DataNode
6279 Jps
```

and bash file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/hadoop-two/jdk1.7.0_71
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/user/hadoop-two/hadoop-2.6.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop
export SPARK_HOME=/home/user/hadoop-two/spark-1.4.0
```

Comment: If anyone has facing same problem, let me know ..finally i solved this

Comment: Yeah sure, please tell us.

Comment: i added answer below, please see it and let me know if anything not working.

Comment: This error: "Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master." is not the source error. You'd have to take a look at yarn logs to find out why YARN wasn't able to run your app.

Comment: yeah..problem was i hadnt set JAVA and HADOOP_CONF_DIR in spark-env.sh file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Spark, and Configure along with above setting up environment variables.
Configure the `JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_CONF_DIR`  in `conf/spark-env.sh` file:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/user/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/jdk1.8.0_60
```

and Define the slave(put dns names of slaves) in spark Conf directory:

```
conf/slaves
```

and start the spark on YARN by using command:

```
bin/spark-shell --master yarn-client
```

Thats It You done !!!!